# M language - extract 5 digit numbers only from string

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I am trying to write a custom column in M to detect whether the field contains a 5 digit number, and then extract that 5 digit number into a new column. When employees incur an expense, they need to specify the job number if its for a job. If not, they usually type in text.

IF text.contains number like "#####" then have the new column have that 5 digit number, else null.

I am having incredible difficult on how to write in M. I tried doing this in

Comment: Can there be leading zero's?  Are you examining the entire contents of the cell?  Or is there mixed text and numbers?  Seems you could just check to see if the number is between `10000` and `99999`

Comment: There are no leading zeros. Job numbers start from 1. Sometimes the employee writes J infront of the 5 digit number, most times they do not.

Comment: Do the job numbers start from `1`, or from `10000`?  (*You wrote they are five-digit numbers*)

Comment: They start from 10000

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in column [Column1] then try

Add column.. custom column ... with formula:

```
= try if Number.From([Column1])>0 and Text.Length(Text.From([Column1]))=5 then [Column1] else null otherwise null
```

that looks for Column1 being something that can evaluate to a number, and that has a length of 5 characters when viewed as a string, otherwise puts a null. This allows for leading zeroes like '01234 but does not attempt to account for mixed text/numbers such as A12345

[image]

if you need to remove alphas, try

```
= if Text.Length(Text.Select(Text.From([Column1]),{"0".."9"}))=5 then Text.Select(Text.From([Column1]),{"0".."9"}) else null
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given what you have written, that valid entries will be in the range of 10,000 to 99,999 and may or may not be preceded by a `J`, you can add a column to detect that.

```
//Ensure Column1 (or whatever it's real name is) is of type text and NOT any
   #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "Job Number", each 
        let 
            x = Text.TrimStart(Text.Upper([Column1]),"J"),
            n = try Number.From(x) otherwise 0
        in 
            if n>=10000 and n<100000 then n else null)
```

[image]